# Is this a grep bug?

Tags: regex, grep

I expect

```
egrep -i "((\w)\2){4,}" /usr/share/dict/words
```

to match the word 'subbookkeeper', but it does not.

Thoughts?

Comment: The chances of there being a bug in grep, compared to the chances of you not understanding grep, are infinitesimally small.  The idea that the tools could be wrong should not be in your head unless you've asked many people for help first.

Comment: Please describe EXACTLY what you want. You could match subbookkeeper with the pattern `^subbookkeeper$` - so describe your "pattern", give examples you want to match, and examples that should not match.

Comment: @dognose I want to match any word in the words file with a continuous sequence of double letters of length eight or more.

Comment: @AndyLester This was exactly my approach. I tested another grep system and the pattern matched. I felt this info was not terribly relevant at the time, but now it seems that I should have included it.

Comment: @macawm Then your pattern is incorrect, it would for instance match 2 numbers in a row, as \w stands for [A-Za-z0-9_] see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes

Comment: There are different versions of `egrep` on different systems. GNU Coreutils `egrep` apparently does support this syntax (see vaichidrewar's answer, confirmed by experiment). Apparently the version on MacOS, probably from BSD, does not.

Comment: @KeithThompson This is the case, I am using FreeBSD 2.5.1 grep and these differences are highly annoying.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty `/usr/share/dict/words` only contains...er...**words**

Comment: A) What if (some implementation of) /usr/share/dict/words contained 'l33t'? B) The more restrictive the pattern, the better it can perform, and you will also get into the habit of writing the most restrictive patterns possible

Comment: Are you sure your `egrep` supports `\w`? This is certainly not universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that egrep is not resetting captured groups on repeats. Not sure if this is a bug or just ambiguity in what the notation implies. If you manually repeat then it should work:

```
egrep -i "(\w)\1(\w)\2(\w)\3(\w)\4" /usr/share/dict/words
```

However, it is strange that this does not work. This does work in perl:

```
perl -lne "print if /((\w)\2){3}/" /usr/share/dict/words
```

BTW, egrep does support {m,n} syntax. This proves that:

```
egrep -i "a{2}" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Comment: After a little testing, it seems that the patterns {m,} and {,n} are not working for egrep. The pattern {m,n} works as expected.

Comment: See my comment on @AndyLester's proposed answer. \w{4,} does what it "should", but not ((\w)\2){4,}. Seems that the combination of the {m,n} syntax and the backreference (or possibly just the more complex "atom" (see `re_format(7)`)) is causing problems

Comment: Thanks for `re_format(7)` reference. It actually states under the _BUGS_ section "Back references are a dreadful botch...somewhat vaguely defined...Avoid using them". I personally disagree with this statement. But that's what the docs say :(

Answer (score 3):

Apparently egrep doesn't support `{m,n}` repeat syntax:

```
$ egrep -i '((\w)\2)((\w)\4)((\w)\6)' words 
bookkeeper
bookkeeping
subbookkeeper
$ egrep -i '((\w)\2)((\w)\4)((\w)\6)((\w)\8)' words 
subbookkeeper
```

If you spell out the groups, it works.

This is on my Mac.

Comment: It seems this may be the case. I cannot find it stated that it does not support this syntax.

Comment: Note to all: BSD grep != GNU grep

Comment: FWIW, the `re_format(1)` manpage suggests that OP's expectation is accurate. Contrast with the regex `\w{4,}` which does match all words with more than 4 letters (again, in line with OP's expectations).

Comment: Andy, you write "Apparently egrep doesn't support {m,n} repeat syntax:" <--- re {m,n}   `echo 1111 | grep -o 1{2}`  <-- won't work.  You need e.g. -P or -E  "grep (GNU grep) 2.21"  Though isn't egrep meant to be -E.. I guess BSD is a bit primitive there.. hope it has improved.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct and there is not a bug. `/usr/share/dict/words` does not contain the word "subbookkeeper".

Comment: My file does have this word.

Comment: `/usr/share/dict/words` varies from one system to another. On one system I use, it's 99171 lines and doesn't contain "subbookkeeper"; on another, it's 479623 lines and does contain "subbookkeeper".

Answer (score 0):

On my freebsd system it did find match

```
[vaibhavc@freebsd-vai ~]$ cat acb
subbookkeeper

[vaibhavc@freebsd-vai ~]$ egrep "((\w)\2){4,}" -i acb
subbookkeeper
```

Comment: I do not know how to add above code as comment to illustrate the point. But I understand that it is not an answer.

Comment: Which version of egrep does your system have? I have 2.5.1

Comment: Mine is also the same : egrep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD